# How to allign control in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How to align the control in code behind.

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</<Grid>

<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.row="0"/>
```

In code behind, I want to add the `DataGrid` in to that Grid.

```
DataGrid dt = new DataGrid();

// how to add above the grid in to that 
// layoutroot in second row.
```

Comment: Just add it and set the `Grid.Row="1"` as you already have 2 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Grid.SetRow() and Grid.SetColumn() functions to set positions from code behind.

```
Grid.SetRow(dt,1); // set position
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(dt); // add control into the Grid
```

Answer (score 2):

For second row, set the Grid.Row property as below:

```
   DataGrid dt = new DataGrid();
   Grid.SetRow(dt ,1);

   LayoutRoot.Children.Add(dt);
```